# Awk/Sed add a column to index data

Tags: awk, sed

I have a one-column data file

```
124993
85422
124972
107596
124934
110663
124993
113757
124993
112686
124961
119334
124972
123040
124989
124620
124965
124965
```

I want add a column to index row so that i can plot them in gnuplot. The index should be generated via rule index=row/2+1 (Start from row 0). As result, the generated data should be like

```
1 124993
1 85422
2 124972
2 107596
3 124934
3 110663
4 124993
4 113757
```

How to do this by awk or sed command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NR`, the current line number starting with 1, in `awk`. Add one to `NR` and convert it to an int, that will do the trick.

```
awk '{print int((NR+1)/2) " " $0}' datafile
```